# How could I integrate fbinfer with my maven project?

Tags: maven

I'm new to fbinfer. I need to integrate my maven project with fbinfer for static code analysis.

Comment: https://fbinfer.com/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks. Gone through above link already. Even though I didn't get anything

Answer (score 0):

Answering this a little late but Sonatype just launched a free Code quality and Software Composition Analysis (SCA) solution called Lift for devs using GitHub: http://lift.dev/

The list of included analyzers includes FBInfer and it takes two clicks (authorize GitHub app) to integrate your Maven application with  Lift/FBInfer, thereby eliminating the pain of manually setting up an analyzer.
https://help.sonatype.com/lift/included-analyzers